# Finding a basis with Change of Basis

Tags: vector-spaces

> Find the coordinate vector for v relative to the basis S = {v1, v2, v3} for $R^3$.
>   $$v = (2,-1,3);$$
>   $$v1 = (1,0,0); v2 = (2,2,0); v3 = (3,3,3);$$

So I did and I got the coordinate vector space as `(v)s = (3, -2, 1)`. I do not believe that this answer is wrong. So now I am at the next question.

> Consider the coordinate vector: 
>   $$ [w]s = 
> \left[ \begin{array}{c}
> 6 \\
> -1 \\
> 4
> \end{array} \right]$$
>   Find w if S is the basis of the first question.

I have no idea how to do this as my textbook is not accurate. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer to the first part is correct.

The second question is essentially the reverse process. If you know what the coordinate vector for w is relative to the basis S, can you "unpack" that coordinate vector to recover the original vector w?

Comment: how do you unpack this

Comment: when you said that the coordinate vector for v relative to the basis S was (3, -2, 1), think about what this means. Why was it that answer? Therefore, if the coordinate vector for w relative to the basis S is (6, -1, 4), what does that mean for w?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}6\\\!\!-1\\4\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\3\end{pmatrix}\iff$$

$$\begin{align*}a+2b+3c&=6\\
2b+3c&=-1\\
3c&=4\end{align*}$$

Well, now just find $\,a,b,c\,$ and these will be your coordinates for your vector wrt the given basis. The inverse process you already did, just as John pointed out.

Comment: It wouldn't be like this. 

If $\ \ v=A_s[v]s$,
 
then $\\ w=A_s[w]s$
$$\therefore w= \left[ \begin{array}{c}
1&2&3 \\
0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array} \right]\cdot 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
6 \\
-1 \\
4
\end{array} \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
16 \\
10 \\
12
\end{array} \right]$$